# Going to the movies

Tags: pattern, visual, knowledge

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Although the 12 film posters displayed above (click on them for a larger version) may seem random, they follow a certain pattern. One of them, however, doesn't belong here.
**Can you find the pattern? And which film (poster) doesn't belong here?**

*Note: There is an actual pattern to the film posters, so the order matters. It's not about whether one film poster doesn't show something while the others do (or vice versa), or whether a film has a different theme than the others.*

Comment: is the arrangement of 4 x 3 or 3 x 4 (instead of a single column) matters?

Comment: @Alex No that doesn't matter, they could have been a single column but I put them next to each other to save space. You have to 'read' them row-wise, so first row from left to right, then second row from left to right etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think these are in order by:

> The month and day of their initial release.
>  Blackhat: **Jan 8 (2015)**
>  The Messengers: **Feb 2 (2007)**
>  16 Blocks: **Mar 3 (2006)**
>  Leatherheads: **Apr 4 (2008)**
>  M:i:III: **May 5 (2006)**
>  ...Zohan: **Jun 6 (2008)**
>  King Arthur: **Jul 7 (2004)**
>  Into the Storm: **Aug 8 (2014)**
>  Moneyball: **Sep 9 (2011)**
>  Addicted: **Oct 10 (2014)**
>  American Sniper: **Nov 11 (2014)**
>  Girl w Tattoo: **Dec 12 (2011)**

And as you can probably tell from that list:

> Each one was released on a day when the day of the month matched the month of the year (2/2, 3/3, 4/4, etc.)

Except:

> Blackhat, which was released on Jan 8, so it's the one that doesn't belong.
> (I'm guessing 1/1 is not a great movie release day!)

Comment: Well done! 1/1 isn't very popular indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my observation about the posters (though it doesn't use knowledge so it is likely wrong):

> All of the posters show a person's face, except for Addicted, which is the odd one out (Into the storm needs to be magnified to see a face)

Here is another observation, though it doesn't really take into account the order:

> All of the movies have a male actor as the first billed (first to show in the credits as ordered by IMDB) cast member, except for The Messengers who has Kirsten Stewart as its first billed cast member

Comment: As you already expected, that's not it. The knowledge tag is indeed relevant. I'll try to explain the question a bit more.